# Hex array to Float

Tags: c, arrays, hex

I have an array of

```
unsigned char array_a[4] = {0x00,0x00,0x08,0x4D};
unsigned char val[4];
float test;
```

what I want to do is combine all the elements and store it to val to make it 0x0000084D and converter it to float, which is 2125.

I tried memcpy

```
 memcpy(val,array_a,4);
 val[4] = '\0';
```

but still not work.

Comment: try `memcpy(&test,array_4,sizeof(float))` but beware of endianness

Comment: `val[4] = '\0';` ... Why? It's not a string, and that index is out of bounds.

Comment: Explain "still not work". What do you get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, `0x0000084D` is the big endian representation of the *integer value* 2125, not IEEE float.

Second, no need to copy to another char array (and accessing the 5th element out of bounds in an attempt to "nul-terminate" the array). That part makes no sense.

To convert this array to an integer on your host, copy it in a standardized 32 bit integer first, then convert it according to the endianness of your machine (else you'd get a bad value on a little endian machine)

```
  unsigned char array_a[4] = {0x00,0x00,0x08,0x4D};
  uint32_t the_int;
  memcpy(&the_int,array_a,sizeof(uint32_t));
  the_int = ntohl(the_int);

  printf("%d\n",the_int);
```

or without any external conversion libs using bit shifting making it endian-independent:

```
  uint32_t the_int = 0;
  int i;
  for (i=0;i<sizeof(uint32_t);i++)
  {
     the_int <<= 8;
     the_int += array_a[i];
  }
```

you get 2125 all right, now you can assign it to a float if you like

```
float test = the_int;
```

Comment: If you use bit shifts instead of memcpy, you can make the code endianess independent. No need for non-standard things like `ntohl` which will only work on a few systems.

Comment: @Lundin okay, provided full bitshift solution (cooked it right now, seems to work, even if I don't like the first useless bitshift)

Comment: If would write it as `uint32_t the int = array_a[0] << 24 | array_a[1] << 16...` (with care for implicit type promotions).

Comment: @Lundin that's the problem, you need to write lots of `(uint32_t)`s there :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala But the compiler would potentially generate faster machine code with a single line, than with a loop.

Comment: @Lundin I suppose you've **never** heard of the as-if rule?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala The compiler will perhaps not be able to unroll the loop because of the initial shift. Impossible to tell without a specific hardware in mind.

Comment: My attempt is just functional. I didn't test it on goldbolt, mind :) it works, but probably not optimal.